# <no Python frame> when trying to install / uninstall any package

Tags: python-3.x

ive tried to import torch (ive allready pip3 installed it) but when running the program then it says no module found so then i try to uninstall it and it says no python frame so  i cant reinstall it through terminal
im on windows 11 using vscode studio
python 3.12

```
> PS C:\Users\Dogne\Code\Gamer-Ai> pip uninstall torch
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'C:\Users\samue\python.exe'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  safe_path = 0
  import site = 1
  is in build tree = 0
  stdlib dir = 'C:\Users\Dogne\Code\Gamer-Ai\Lib'
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\Users\\samue\\python.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\Dogne\\Code\\Gamer-Ai'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\samue'
  sys.platlibdir = 'DLLs'
  sys.executable = 'C:\\Users\\samue\\python.exe'
  sys.prefix = 'C:\\Users\\Dogne\\Code\\Gamer-Ai'
  sys.exec_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\samue'
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\Users\\samue\\python311.zip',
    'C:\\Users\\Dogne\\Code\\Gamer-Ai\\Lib',
    'C:\\Users\\samue\\DLLs',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00006f80 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>
```

i tried to reinstall torch it but   kept coming up and wouldent let me import it in my code